# Ruby on Rails install and run problem

Tags: 14.04, apt, mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I installed Ruby + Rails and its dependencies on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04 using the following commands,

Pre Install Checklist

```
sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Add apt repositories from the Brightbox site.

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ruby2.2 ruby2.2-dev
sudo apt-get install ruby-switch
sudo apt-get install bundler
sudo ruby-switch --set ruby2.2

ruby -v
```

Install Other Dependencies

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev 
libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev 
libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev
```

Install MySQL

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
```

Install ImageMagick

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Install Rails

```
gem install rails --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

Install SublimeText

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Create a new app

```
mkdir projects
cd projects
rails new testapp
cd testapp
```

Open project in sublime text

```
subl -n .
```

Run rails server

```
bin/rails server
```

**I didn't get any error during installation but when I ran the command `bin/rails server` it gave me the following error**

```
Ignoring json-1.8.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json --version 1.8.3
Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:48:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.1/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.1/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/arif/projects/testapp/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/arif/projects/testapp/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /home/arif/projects/testapp/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/arif/projects/testapp/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I'm badly stuck, please help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably have noticed, this is due to a JRE error. Make sure you have the following entries in your gem file:

```
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
```

I have seen [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202324/execjs-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime-but-execjs-and-therubyracer-are-in) in SE where users were able to solve this issue by installing nodejs. To do this, in your terminal run:

> `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Comment: Yes, it worked :) But still its giving me this warning " 

Ignoring json-1.8.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json --version 1.8.3
Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring. "